# In Pharo is there a way to set the debugger window default width using em's an the equivalent?

Tags: debugging, fonts, smalltalk, pharo

I'm still using Pharo 1.3 with Omni-Browser and the Dejavu size 12 font.  The default is size 9.  So I made my fonts bigger. Now when a new debugger pops up and I click 'Debug' or 'Create' some of the buttons are cut off on the right side.

Where can I adjust the default width of the debugger?

Is there a way to make the width dependent upon the default font size?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for a user to do that. You'd have to go into the code for the Debugger and make the change. If you're comfortable doing that, and just want a hack for your own personal image, the following will work...

1. In Debugger>>addOptionalButtonsTo:at:plus:, after the line `buttons := self customButtonRow.`, add the following line `buttonRowWidth := buttons initialExtent x.` When prompted, "declare instance".
2. Change Debugger>>openFullMorphicLabel: to the following

   ```
   "Open a full morphic debugger with the given label"

   | window |
   window := UIManager default openDebugger: self fullMorphicLabel: aLabelString.
   window
       width: buttonRowWidth + (2 * window borderWidth).
   ```